# An error occurred while performing face recognition using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I took a face recognition lecture using opencv and I followed it, but I get an error

```
import cv2

model = 'data/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel'
config = 'data/deploy.prototxt'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Camera open failed!')
    exit()

net = cv2.dnn.readNet(model, config)

if net.empty():
    print('Net open failed!')
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        break

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
    net.setInput(blob)
    detect = net.forward()

    detect = detect[0, 0, :, :]
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]

    for i in range(detect.shape[0]):
        confidence = detect[i, 2]
        if confidence < 0.5:
            break

        x1 = int(detect[i, 3] * w)
        y1 = int(detect[i, 4] * h)
        x2 = int(detect[i, 5] * w)
        y2 = int(detect[i, 6] * h)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0))

        label = 'Face: %4.3f' % confidence
        cv2.putText(frame, label, (x1, y1 - 1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 255, 0),1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following error message

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-06c753864c1d> in <module>
     23     blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
     24     net.setInput(blob)
---> 25     detect = net.forward()
     26 
     27     detect = detect[0, 0, :, :]

error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build- 
kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) 
!blobs.empty() || inputs.size() > 1 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'
```

what is the problem and what should i do
could anyone advice on this?

version
python                    3.8.5
opencv-python             4.5.1.48

Comment: you may have most common problem - you may have empty image. First check what you have in `blob` - ie. `print(blob)`, `print(type(blob))`

Comment: if you follow some lecture then show link in question (not in comment). Maybe there is mistake or it is updated.